# Terminology for a “group selfie”

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, slang

A [***selfie***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfie) is a kind of casual self-portrait. People often take selfies that include a significant other or multiple friends, and I’m curious whether there is any established terminology or slang for this kind of “group selfie.”

The linked Wikipedia article indicates that they are simply known as “group selfies,” but I suspect that there may be an older or better established term. I’m also curious whether there are specific terms for “couple selfies” featuring a significant other or best friend. Formal English, slang, and jargon terms are all acceptable.

Comment: And if “group selfie” really is the best term for this, that would be a good answer too – I'd like to see the evidence for it one way or the other.

Comment: Or a "self groupie"?

Comment: @Oldcat That sounds like a very different, and euphemistic thing.

Comment: *Selvesies* certainly fits.

Comment: A selfie is a photo taken **by yourself, with your arm outstretched, holding the camera [often a smartphone] backwards.**  Of course it's a matter of opinion, but for me the critical element is "are typically taken with a camera held at arm's length" (as some random person wrote on the wikipedia site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The few sources out there seem to prefer the term *"X" Selfie*, where *X* is replaced by *family, group, etc.*

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any real consensus, except that a true *selfie* is more of a snapshot than an artful application. There are *some* who would claim a selfie must be taken at arms length and not with a mirror or self-timer, but this remains a matter of debate (see comments below!)

Perhaps, the more important distinction falls between a *self-portrait* vs. a *selfie*.  A self-portrait in most usage implies forethought and artfulness. A selfie is an attempt to record oneself in a place or time.  In theory, you could make an artful selfie, but you'd be plundering the territory of self-portraits.

Interestingly, Canon, the camera manufacturer does even not have a terminology for the usage of a self-timer to take a group photo.  They refer to using the self-timer to take "self-portraits or pictures of you with friends and family".

[Here is the source speaking about the self-timer function in their cameras.](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/camera_settings/self_timer_and_timed_exposures.do)

Comment: Given that they are the number one camera manufacturer in the world by market share, their manuals tend to read pretty well.  Canon USA does their own manuals, as does Canon Europe, etc.  (A quick peek at my avatar will tell you that I've put a bit of time in with camera manuals!)  Also of note, that is not a product manual, but rather a source for professional photographers.

Comment: That link is to Canon Professional Network.

Comment: [Another source referring to family selfies](http://thehappyfamilymovement.com/2013/10/how-to-take-awesome-family-portraits-of-your-own-family/)

Comment: [And one saying that a selfie is specifically taken with your arm outstretched compared to a group shot or self-portrait.](http://www.digital-photo-secrets.com/tip/3524/five-surprising-uses-for-your-cameras-self-timer/)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's an improvement, although “selfie” includes more than just pictures taken at arm's length. It also includes handheld mirror pics for certain, and possibly also webcam pics. But probably not self-timer pics, so the Canon document may not be relevant.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I've edited it to reflect that a bit better.  But, as I've stated above.  Mirror pics, etc. are self-portraits.  People have been doing that forever as a means of self-portraiture.

Comment: People have also been holding cameras at arm's length since before 2002. The practice of taking selfies predates the term for it. People definitely use _selfie_ to include mirror pics, and they're part of the summary definition at Wikipedia (linked in the question).

Comment: In that case, why not call a self-timer portrait a selfie then?

Comment: I suspect that selfie is a fuzzy, know it when I see it kind of term. But the essence seems to be casual self portraiture. Self snapshots. Perhaps with a bit of aesthetic judgment.

Comment: @DavidM - since they were rare, "group portraits" with a timer didn't demand a name.  With the facebook and web tossing up loads of self shots, mocking them demanded a derisive term like selfie.

Comment: @Oldcat I would argue they weren't that rare. They've been enough of a part of life in the last 30 years to become a meme in TV shows, particularly sit-coms. Father sets timer, waits, nothing happens, goes to check, picture snaps.  And, numerous other hackneyed comedic variants have been around just as long.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't talk about them. You rolled your eyes and endured them stoically.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Fair enough, but based upon available evidence I stand by my line drawn in the sand.

Comment: @Oldcat Weak argument. If we go ignoring memes that we roll our eyes at … Well, Donald Trump, American Idol, and half of the internet are in serious trouble.

Comment: It isn't an argument that group portraits didn't have a cutesy name that we mocked on the nonexistent internet, it is a plain fact. Group shots were never a 'meme'.

Comment: @oldcat I misunderstood you. My sincerest apologies.  Yet, if you wouldn't consider a timed self-portrait a selfie, then why a timed group portrait?

Comment: @Bradd and Oldcat. I've edited above to reflect a group consensus.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could coin your own. Selfie, Groupie, Couplie.... I might even suggest going a step further and adding a recognizable conformity, as with iPad, iPod--

self-e, group-e, couple-e, family-e (in this case you wouldn't actually pronounced the 'E') variations could be

selfE, self'e, self'E, self-E, self-e, self^e, self, self/e, selfē <---- I like this one.

groupē

couplē

familyē or familē

I may have missed the mark on what you were after...